# Making VBA Word add-in change the default RibbonUI tab

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

(Be kind to me; I'm not a professional developer!)

I've created a custom Word ribbon with all sorts of business-specific functionality. I think it's awesome, but there are some old-school people here who want the built-in "Home" tab to show up by default because that's what they're "used to."

I added a menu option to change the default between the Home Tab and the HMF tab. The problem is that I can't actually figure out how to use the setting to change the active tab.

Here's a snippet of the ribbon code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="HMFRibbon.InitializeRibbon">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab id="HMFTab" label="HMF" insertAfterQ="TabHome">

[...]
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

My STARTUP folder contains an "HMF_Toolbar.dotm" that includes the following code in the "HMFRibbon" module:

```
Public ribRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub InitializeRibbon(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    On Error GoTo DefaultError
    If GetSetting("HMFToolbar", "Defaults", "HMFIsDefault") = "False" Then
        MsgBox ("Leaving 'Home' as default tab")
    Else
        Set ribRibbon = ribbon
        MsgBox ("Activating 'HMFTab'")
        ribRibbon.ActivateTab ("HMFTab")
    End If
    Exit Sub
DefaultError:
    MsgBox ("Could not find default toolbar setting.")
End Sub
```

The code runs the first time a document is open, finds the right default and shows the right message, but doesn't actually change the starting tab to HMFTab. It also only runs when the ribbon is first opened, so even if it worked the first time it wouldn't run when subsequent documents were open (would would again default to "Home").

I tried moving the function to "AutoOpen()" in the HMFRibbon module, but that only fires if I open "HMFRibbon.dotm," not another document with the module loaded.

So... any ideas?

---

EDIT: I should have been clearer. By "default tab," what I really mean is that I want the ribbon to automatically *activate* either the "Home" or "HMF" tab depending on whether HMFIsDefault is true or false.

I've gotten closer by using the Application.AutoOpen function, but it fires before the ribbon is actually loaded, so "active doesn't work! Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oApp As Word.Application

Private Sub oApp_DocumentOpen(ByVal Doc As Document)
    On Error GoTo DefaultError

    If GetSetting("HMFToolbar", "Defaults", "HMFIsDefault") = "False" Then
        MsgBox ("Leaving 'Home' as default tab")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Activating 'HMFTab'")
        HMFRibbon.ribRibbon.ActivateTab ("HMFTab")

    End If
Exit Sub
DefaultError:
    MsgBox ("Could not find default toolbar setting.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you spell out exactly what the user should see? The thing is that "Activating" a tab is a one-time action that causes the ribbon to show that Tab. It's not something that makes that tab any kind of "default". What I suspect the users may want to do one of several things: show just the built-in Home Tab, show just your HMF tab, show both Tabs (perhaps with the built-in Home tab in its usual position and the HMF tab elsewhere, or perhaps the other way around). If that's what you want to do, you also need to modify whether the Home Tab and/or the HMF tabs are *visible*.

Comment: The “default tab” is whichever tab is first on the ribbon. ActivateTab is not going to help. If users can’t agree where the tab should be you either make separate add-ins, or you reach a compromise. There isn’t a “getInsertBefore” callback.

Comment: I should have been clearer. By "default tab," what I really mean is that I want the ribbon to automatically *activate* either the "Home" or "HMF" tab depending on whether HMFIsDefault is true or false. I've gotten closer using the Application.AutoOpen function, but it fires before the ribbon is actually loaded, so "active doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The [IRibbonUI.ActivateTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetab) method can be used for activating ribbon tabs. You just need to pass the Id of the custom Ribbon tab to be activated. You may also find the [IRibbonUI.ActivateTabMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetabmso) method for built controls and [IRibbonUI.ActivateTabQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetabq) which uses the fully qualified name of the tab, which includes the ID and the namespace of the tab.

You may consider using the `insertAfterMso` attribute for the custom ribbon tab if you want to place it after a specific built-in ribbon tab.

Compare the following attributes:

- `insertAfterMso` - Specifies the identifier for the built-in control after which to position this control.
- `insertAfterQ` - Specifies the identifier of a qualified control (that is, a control whose `idQ` property was specified) after which to position this control.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Appreciate the pointer, but I've already got `insertAfterQ="TabHome"` in the ribbon XML. That works without issue and my custom tab shows up second, just like it should. The issue is that I want to make the tab selected by default dynamic based on a setting.

Comment: Use the `IRibbonUI.ActivateTab` method in that case.

Comment: If you look in my original code, I'm using this method. The problem is getting it to fire.

Comment: Try to call the method outside of ribbon callbacks, i.e. when ribbon is fully initialized.